# MySQL join and exclude?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables, table A one with two columns: IP and ID, and table B with columns: ID and extra information. I want to extract the rows in table B for IPs that are not in table A. So if I have a rows in table A with

```
id = 1
ip = 000.000.00
id = 2
ip = 111.111.11
```

and I have rows in table B

```
id = 1
id = 2
```

then, given ip = 111.111.11, how can I return row 1 in table B?

Comment: Change your accepted answer to Marc's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest and most easy-to-read way to spell what you're describing is:

```
SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE `ID` NOT IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `A`)
```

You should be aware, though, that using a subquery for something like this has [historically been slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588846/560648) than doing the same thing with a [self-join](https://www.quora.com/MySQL-How-does-a-self-join-work-and-what-does-it-allow-you-to-accomplish), because it is easier to optimise the latter, which might look like this:

```
SELECT
   `B`.*
FROM
   `B`
LEFT JOIN
   `A` ON `A`.`ID` = `B`.`ID`
WHERE
   `A`.`ID` IS NULL
```

However, technology is improving all the time, and the extent to which this is true (or even *whether* this is true) [depends on the database software you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577188/560648).

You should test both approaches then settle on the best balance of readability and performance for your use case.

Answer (score 33):

```
select b.id, b.* 
from b
left join a on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null
```

This'll pull all the rows in B that have no matching rows in A. You can add a specific IP into the where clause if you want to try for just that one ip.

Comment: why b.id and b.* at this same time - too ambisious

Comment: Because the OP said there's other fields in the table, but didn't specify them. So I'm specifically selecting the fields he included in the question, and put in the `*` to cover the fields he didn't

Comment: so obvious, and yet somehow I couldn't figure this one out on my own, thanks a ton!