# HTML DropDown with Mysqli data and data selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, dropdownbox

I have an html dropdown list which gets the data from mysql table.  I have a second table where I can see which equipment has already been selected for another user for the day.

My question is:

- How do I not display that equipment (BowCode and its Information) and instead go to the next entry.
- It's possible that multiple equipment have been already selected for the day for other users.

My code:

```
$BowDropDown = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM equipment order by BowCode ASC");

while ($row = $BowDropDown->fetch_assoc()){

    if($row['BowCode'] != $BowDropDownDayCheck){}

    if($row['Recurve'] =='1'){
        $value = 'Recurve';
    } else if ($row['Compound'] == '1'){
        $value = 'Compound';
    } else if ($row['Longbow'] == '1'){
        $value ='Longbow';
    }
echo "<option value= " . $row['BowCode'] . ">" . $value . " - " . $row['BowCode'] . " - " . $row['Info'] . " - " . $row['Poundage'] . "</option>";
}
```

I don't know if it is possible or not but maybe the values that are displayed in the dropdown can be visualised like a table view.

[table from where the Equipment is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmeKT.png)

[tabele where the users are stored with the Equipment the use for the day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PyDM.png)

Comment: *"maybe the values that are displayed in the Dropdown can be visualised like a table view."* - as what type of table, an HTML table?

Comment: yes like a html table i dont know if that might be possible

Comment: it sure is possible; is this all you want to do?

Comment: no also and to check if BowCode has already been used for the day. If so then not to Display the bowCode

Comment: Adjust your query to not select items that are in the other table.

Comment: @Michel how to do that ?

Comment: $BowDropDownDayCheck = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM equipment Where Date='$date'");

@Michel thats what i have tried but it didnt do anything

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287246/mysql-join-and-exclude), you need a `join`. To help you, we need some tablenames, columnnames etc.

Comment: @Michel hope the immages helps you with the table names

Comment: Is `BowCode` from the first table identical to `BowID` from the second?

Comment: Yes i know i made the mistake of not Nameing it the same tho i will do it later

Comment: And the table names?

Comment: the first table is called Equipment and the secon one is called comeandtrydaysparticipant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does the job

```
SELECT 
   b.id, b.BowCode, b.Info
FROM Equipment AS b
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT a.BowID
   FROM comeandtrydaysparticipant AS a
   WHERE a.`date`="2018-01-26"
   GROUP BY a.BowID
  ) AS c
ON c.BowID = b.BowCode
WHERE c.BowID IS NULL
;
```

It selects all items not in `comeandtrydaysparticipant` for a particular day.

And the [proof is in the pudding](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3d83/4)

Comment: cool and now when i want to echo the values out in php do i do b.BowCode ?

Comment: Just `BowCode`. The `b.` is an alias for the table Equipment (as `a.` is for that other, very fance tablename ;), it just saves typing.